# Android: Build failure when using R8

Tags: android, build, android-r8

I'm trying to build my project with R8 enabled. However, I get this error:

`./gradlew assembleAndroidTest`

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: void com.cresta.Controller.ensureSaneDefaults() is not being kept as F, but remapped to B
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
```

Comment: Have you upgraded Gradle and the gradle plugin?

Comment: Hey, yes. That didn't help either

Comment: The weird thing is that R8 is fully compatible with ProGuard, unless you are using "full mode". In fact, Android Studio 3.4 comes with R8 enabled by default. Are you building with R8's full mode?

Comment: No. I haven't enabled "full mode". Is it enabled by default? Let me try explicitly disabling it.

Comment: add `android.enableR8=false` in gradle.properties and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported at http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131710444
Please refer to that bug report on resolving the issue once it has been fixed.

Comment: Hey, yes I reported it there too :)